# How to parse this this data in UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places

How to parse this  this data in UIImageView?

This is my code:

```
photos =(
        {
            height = 2988;
            "html_attributions" =                     (
            "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109461257917544660371/photos\">Marie-Claude Brousseau</a>"
                );
                "photo_reference" = "CoQBdwAAAD1yAyXPTuN2ZyRD4VZGAqVTT3ZCWSLe_RHSLx_ea-GLe0TsaRSpqIsHhvTj82GljPJG5y-Lrk6809jI5KzvcUjXroCcaAlEkgDLhQma5xsvA0vF4DwdoEZ0wWUZxXHs01BxedzegpQSgB4zVnzbUaAZaN_D5dEr0UOp4awIExe2EhAISA1lOL6VARBNLg9a1r1tGhQf3RgXpVfnPBtYPH6RY5pqmJE0mQ";
                width = 5312;
            }
        );
```

Comment: You have to ask a question. Explain where you are stuck. This is just code.

Answer (score -1):

Use NSJSONSerialization class as follows:

```
NSData *data = [photos dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *propertyList = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
  options:0 error:NULL];
```

Comment: You should provide "photos" as an NSString to make it work:

Comment: His string isn't json.  It looks like he `NSLog`d a dictionary